# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on CDN

Tags: css, performance, google-chrome, cdn

Recently, on the website I'm working on, I've noticed the below error in the Chrome console.

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
>   http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

The bootstrapcdn.com URL works when I try to open it in a different tab. It's really slowing the page load time but it's only occurring in this browser, and only on my PC.  I checked on Chrome from another PC and nothing changes.

I tried clearing my cookies but that did not work.  Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Have you tired in other browser?(your pc)

Comment: @alirezasafian, yes as I said in the question it is only occurring on my browser on my PC

Comment: Please, try it to open in chrome incognito.

Comment: I had problems with other different CDN services - not always - not at all - occasionally - but that still worries me a lot.

Comment: I've seen this issue with various CDNs. For example jQuery fails to load from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js with this error and my site appears broken. Happens maybe 1 in 20 loads.

Comment: Try using https instead of http

Comment: try using: `src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"`

Comment: Try it in incognito mode.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and it's pretty strange, can't reproduce on other computers.  Could it be blocked by anti-virus somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Download the file & assets then serve it from your own server.

You'll lose the benefit distributed content, but gain stability equivalent to your own server and be able to set your own caching rules.

If you really want/need your assets distributed then sign up to an existing CDN service and start sending all your assets through there.