# JS and CSS fail to load in Chrome, intermittently (25%). Getting an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, cdn

I am running a Flask web app on localhost, for development. I do a Ctrl+F5 (after I have made a change to JS or CSS). **Once in 3-4 such instances** I get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET errors in the Chrome console, for **SOME** of the external JS/CSS (Bootstrap, Jquery etc) that I am fetching from CDNs. But there's no pattern to it. I am getting this from MaxCDN, cdnjs.cloudflare.com, and code.jquery.com, but not all at once.

Some of these errors are:

`GET https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

`GET https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

`GET https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

I am getting similar issues in Firefox:

`Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js”.`

This is happening only on my laptop. On another laptop, running the same code on that laptop's localhost, and accessed and hard refreshed through that laptop's browser works fine.

This issue started occurring only recently after I reinstalled Windows on my laptop.

I looked at some of the other questions on SO such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169711/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-connection-reset-on-cdn), but that didn't help.

Comment: If it only happens on one computer, it's most likely that computer has issues. Maybe bad wifi or some other issues but from your description it doesn't sound like anything is wrong with the cdns

Comment: I'm not facing any other connectivity issues on this laptop. I've checked after stopping my firewall (ZoneAlarm) that didn't help either. Also, not sure why the firewall would block requests intermittently.

Btw, the other laptop is also on the same WiFi network.

Comment: By bad wifi I mean the wifi on your laptop, not your router. Either way, if it is only happening on one computer, then don't spend too much time on it

Comment: I have the exact same issue.  After 2 or 3 refreshes with dev tools open and cache disabled it will start working, but I don't get why it's dropping so often, other files in my web app coming from AWS seem to be fine, it really only seems to be CDN files...